# Beta testing a chromecast app with a custom receiver?

Tags: android, chromecast

As far as I know the only way to test an Android Chromecast app with a custom receiver is to register the devices in the Chromecast console. This works fine for development, but what if I want to test the app with multiple users in different locations with their own Chromecasts without publishing the app to the Chromecast app store? Is there a way to accomplish this or do I have to register every single Chromecast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for similar question on G+ about "private" publish of the Custom Receiver:

> ... pick a country we haven't launched in in the developer console to
>   promote your app and it won't show up anywhere since we don't have a
>   site there to promote it. I know it's hacky, and as I said, we're
>   working on making it better, but this should help you in the short
>   run. Aruba, for example, while a beautiful place, doesn't have a
>   [chromecast.com/apps](http://chromecast.com/apps) page, so effectively, you get the desired result.

https://plus.google.com/u/0/112484414944760874420/posts/QAgayNmRRNu

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking too. Seems like a decent enough solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to get their serial numbers and register them on the Cast Developer Console.

Comment: So that's the only way to do it? There's no way to "publish" an app for a closed beta group like on the Android store without registering each and every Chromecast device?

Comment: No, currently that is not possible.